# Multiple wait using notify all

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++14

I wish to use condition variable with wait.

I have create a program with 10 threads and each thread wait a signal `notify_all()` from the main thread. But It goes to deadlock and I don't wish to understand why.

```
#include <iostream>           // std::cout
#include <thread>             // std::thread
#include <mutex>              // std::mutex, std::unique_lock
#include <condition_variable> // std::condition_variable
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

std::mutex mtx;
std::condition_variable cv;
int xx = 0;

void print_id (int id) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
    cout<<"Start thread id  " << id << "  \n";

    for(int i=0; i<9; i++)
    {
        cout<<"Thread " << id << " i " << i <<"\n";
        cv.wait(lck);
    }
}

void go()
{
    cv.notify_all();
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
       //Some works for threads
        cv.notify_all();
    }
}

int main ()
{
    std::thread threads[10];
    for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
        threads[i] = std::thread(print_id,i);

    std::cout << "10 threads ready to race...\n";
    go();                       // go!

    for (auto& th : threads) th.join();
}
```

Comment: You can't call `wait` unless you have something to wait for. And you can't call `notify_all` unless you have something to notify the threads of. And, worst of all, your mutex doesn't protect anything! It's supposed to be protecting the thing you're waiting for and the thing you're notifying about!

Answer (score 3):

This is not how condition variables work.

The main thing to realize is that condition variables cannot reliably signal an event all on their own. In particular, `wait()` calls may return spuriously, that is, without anyone ever calling `notify`.

Instead what you need is a *logical condition* in your surrounding program that the condition variable is tied to. You call notify whenever that condition changes and have `wait` check the condition, [either as part of a surrounding loop or inside the `wait` by providing a checker predicate function as an argument to the call](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait).

The other problem to watch out for is that while waits cannot continue without a notify occurring (logically, assuming there are no spurious wakeups), the opposite is not true. That is, the `go()` function might run to completion even before the `print_id` function has reached the first wait. That wait will then be blocked forever, since there are no more notifies on the way. Notifies do not wait for waits, they are fire-and-forget operations.

In correct use of condition variables this is not an issue, as the wait simply awaits for the logical condition to change. If that change already occurred before the wait call, you detect it and do not call wait in the first place.

What you probably wanted here is the behavior of a [barrier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/barrier). You can easily implement your own barrier using a `int` counter as the condition and a `condition_variable` and a `mutex` for synchronization.

Comment: Re, "Notifies do not wait for waits..."  Another way to say it is, `cv.notify()` and `cv.notify_all()` do not do _anything at all_ unless some other thread is already waiting in a `cv.wait()` call.